# Not able to access company site while on the company domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, domain-name, clickonce

Currently, our setup at the office goes something like this:

If you're on a computer that is out of the office, you can go to http://site.domain.com/folder
and you're fine. The page will show up.

If you're on the office domain, it won't. Instead you have to use http://server/folder.

Now, I'm told that this is because we have our main provider forward site.domain.com/ to our server here (while keeping the main company site hosted on their servers).

I'm wondering why, a little more specifically, this might be and if there is a workaround, or a setting that I can have the admin make so that in the office, all users will be able to go to http://sub.domain.com/folder. I ask because I am deploying the software we're making there via ClickOnce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a DNS zone in the AD DNS servers where the zone is site.domain.com and use a cname to point it to the server's internal IP.

This way site.domain.com will resolve to the internal IP for anyone in the office, and anyone outside won't be effected.  And other public names you have registered will continue to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If "server" resolves to a local (LAN) IP address and "site.domain.com" resolves to a public Internet IP address, and the office network is behind a NAT, [then here is the explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/37421/accessing-a-website-via-the-webservers-public-ip-from-a-pc-within-the-same-lan/37428#37428).

Assuming this is your problem, you have two ways of solving it:

- The Right (but complicated) Way: set up a DNS server on your local network which will serve internal IP addresses for requests to site.domain.com.
- The Quick and Dirty Way: modify the hosts file on each computer in your office network so that "site.domain.com" resolves to the same address as "server". Of course if you then take a computer out of the office (e.g. if it's a laptop) then you have to reverse the modification.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably down to DNS, you will have a public IP address assigned to site.domain.com.

You should ask your admin to look into [Split DNS](http://www.isaserver.org/tutorials/You_Need_to_Create_a_Split_DNS.html)